# Remove array values from AsyncStorage in react native

Tags: react-native, local-storage, asyncstorage

I am storing array of values to a single key using asyncstorage, I am trying to remove the values but it remains even if I remove it.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(“fault”,JSON.stringify(id));
```

where id is array of values.  How to remove the id from the storage later?

Comment: why does `AsyncStorage.removeItem('fault',(error) => {
  if (!error) {
  alert(" Clear success ");
  }
 });` not work?

Comment: I am getting the alert but the value remains